# Axis not appearing in the correct location ListPointPlot3D

Tags: plotting, formatting

So when you make a 3D plot in mathematica, Plot3D, ListPlot3D, ListPointPlot3D, etc. the side of the box the axis show up on usually happens automatically. That is, the orient themselves so they're always on the front most side of the box. This keeps them visible.

I have created a ListPointPlot3D, but the axes are not orienting themselves correctly. And they're hidden behind the data.

[image: Plot with poorly placed axis labels]

I can't find any documentation on how to set where they show up specifically.

Now this figure is fairly complicated to produce, which I suspect might be the problem.

```
ListPointPlot3D[Map[{#} &, ListOfXYZCoords], 
 PlotStyle->ListOfColors, 
 PlotLegends->BarLegend[{"Rainbow",
  {Min[ListOfXYZCoords],Max[ListOfXYZCoords]}}]]
```

In some instances, I found that removing the legend fixes the problem, in others, I've found it does not make a difference. I think setting them manually for now would be the best option.

Comment: Please provide some data that exhibits the problem.

Comment: ListOfXYZCoords = Table[RandomReal[1,3],500];

ListOfColors =  Table[ColorData["Rainbow", RandomReal[1]], 500];

Comment: With v12.1.1 on a Mac I cannot reproduce the problem with the data and code provided. Since `PlotLegend` is not a valid option in current versions (`PlotLegends` is), I assume you are using an older version. Recommend that you evaluate `$Version` and include that with your code.

Comment: Take a look at [`AxesEdge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxesEdge).

Comment: @BobHanlon, that was a typo on my part. I am using PlotLegends.

Comment: @CarlWoll, that was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!